# Function for a series of values

Tags: functions

What is the best way to find a function based on a series of data points?

The data I have so far:

fx(1,000) = 30,000

fx(10,000) = 8,000

fx(100,000) = 1,500

fx(1,000,000) = 300

fx(10,000,000) = 70

Comment: Since there are (literally) infinitely many functions that will meet any finite set of requirements, you'll have to be more specific about what sort of function you want. Do you want a polynomial - in which case, maybe you want the one of lowest degree?

Comment: Lagrange interpolation might be the best bet here.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Thank you for your question.  We can better help you answer it if you give us more context, as well as a summary of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general procedure to answer a question like this. There are **infinitely many** functions satisfying these properties, taking any value at all at other points.

However, you can impose specific requirements on $f$, such as $f$ being a polynomial $f = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots + a_n x^n$, and then ask what the $a_i$ are. If there are $n+1$ data points, there will generally be a unique answer. If there are more than $n+1$ data points, you might look for the *least squares* solution, which is an approximation which makes the smallest 'total error' on your data, in a specific sense. See [Least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) on Wikipedia. You might also want to read about [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation), in which you more pragmatically predict values near some data, given some data.

In general, [regression analysis (Wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) is the field of choosing parameters in a given form of $f$ like $f(x) = a \exp(-bx)$ to fit specific data.

Without more specific information, it's impossible to give a single answer to your question.